# Dropdownlist in MVC with Where cluase in entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am new to MVC. I want to fill Dropdownlist only where `Account_Type = "D"`.
Here is my **Edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Account_Code, "Account_Code", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Account_Code", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account_Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my **Edit Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.Account_Code = new SelectList(db.Chart_Of_Account, "Account_Code", "Account_Desc", student.Account_Code);
}
```

Comment: `db.Chart_Of_Account.Where(a => a.Account_Type == "D")`

Comment: And change the `ViewBag` property to `AccountCodeList` and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Account_Code, (SelectList)ViewBag.AccountCodeList)` and delete the 3rd parameter of your `SelectList` constructor

Comment: @StephenMuecke Great! it works :) Just I want know if I want to have multicolumn dropdownlist or an autocomplete textbox with multiple columns.

Comment: There is no such thing as a multicolumn dropdownlist in html. Not sure what you need, but you would need a jquery plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `.Where()` clause to filter your data

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  var accountCodes = db.Chart_Of_Account.Where(a => a.Account_Type == "D");
  ViewBag.AccountCodeList = new SelectList(accountCodes , "Account_Code", "Account_Desc");
}
```

Note I have changed the name of the `ViewBag` property and removed the 3rd parameter of the `SelectList` contructor (its ignored when binding to a property)

Your view should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Account_Code, (SelectList)ViewBag.AccountCodeList)
```